# Made a collection of files, how to access those nodes? xslt

Tags: xml, xslt

The structure is that we have a xml file that represents an entire issue of a magazine, and then in the same folder there is a subfolder that has all of the xml files that represent each page of the magazine.

Using this website and a baby book for xslt, I've gotten to the point where I can transform individual pages into SVGs, and I can create a list of files, but I need the connective tissue between the two ideas.

If I run this xsl on my mets.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    exclude-result-prefixes="xs"
    version="2.0">

    <xsl:output indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:for-each select="collection('./alto/?select=*.xml')" >
        <xsl:element name='file'>
            <xsl:value-of select="tokenize(document-uri(.), '/')[last()]"/>
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I get something that looks like this:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <file>bmtnabt_1917-07_01_0001.alto.xml</file>
    <file>bmtnabt_1917-07_01_0002.alto.xml</file>
    <file>bmtnabt_1917-07_01_0003.alto.xml</file>
    <file>bmtnabt_1917-07_01_0004.alto.xml</file>
    <file>bmtnabt_1917-07_01_0005.alto.xml</file>
```

So far so good. But how do I actually access nodes inside the individual files?
This doesn't work:

```
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:for-each select="collection('./alto/?select=*.xml')" >
            <xsl:element name='file'>
                <xsl:value-of select="tokenize(document-uri(.), '/')[last()]"/>
                <xsl:value-of select="alto/Description"/>
            </xsl:element>
        </xsl:for-each>
        </xsl:template>
```

for example, does NOT process the alto/Description nodes. Thoughts on how to process those nodes  in this loop? Getting around inside the file is not an issue (I have a working script that does what I want to individual alto files)

Comment: The plot thickens. Somehow './alto/? is NOT getting the alto folder of the currently being applied xml.

Comment: So how does one of the files look like? Which data do you want to read out? Do those files have a root element named `alto` with a child named `Description`?

Comment: I was actually able to solve my problem with: <xsl:variable name="filesold" select="collection('./alto/?select=*.xml')"/>    and then a foreach $files/a:alto/a:Description. Now I have a different problem, namely getting the collection to load based on the location of the document and not of the stylesheet, I've created a new item for that, though.